# mysql LOAD XML INFILE loading mostly null values

Tags: mysql, xml, database, etl, staging

I'm not getting an error but I'm getting an undesired results and not sure the best way to handle it. I have an xml file with a list property `<tags>` when I stage this I want each tag to be a single row so it makes it easier to insert into the final 3 table where posts and tags have an N-N relationship and all tags are unique.

this is the command I run, and it creates the desired number of records.

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'myfile.xml' INTO TABLE stage ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<tag>';
Query OK, 11 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 11  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

however when I run `select * from stage` I get the following result set, which is basically useless.

```
username|real_name|post_date|profile_url|is_mod|allow_pm|followers|message|tag
RickDude|NULL     |NULL     |NULL       |NULL  |NULL    |NULL     |NULL   |#cool
RickDude|NULL     |NULL     |NULL       |NULL  |NULL    |NULL     |NULL   |#awesome
RickDude|NULL     |NULL     |NULL       |NULL  |NULL    |NULL     |NULL   |#money
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

sql table create script

```
CREATE TABLE stage(
    username NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    real_name NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    post_date VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    profile_url NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    is_mod VARCHAR(5) NULL, 
    allow_pm VARCHAR(5) NULL, 
    followers VARCHAR(11) NULL,
    message NVARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    tag NVARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

xml file

```
<posts>
    <post>
        <username>RickDude</username>
        <tags>
            <tag>#cool</tag>
            <tag>#awesome</tag>
            <tag>#money</tag>
        </tags>
        <real_name>Richard Sanchez</real_name>
        <post_date>Aug. 8, 2015</post_date>
        <profile_url>https://example.com/profiles/RickDude</profile_url>
        <is_mod>True</is_mod>
        <allow_pm>True</allow_pm>
        <followers>1000001</followers>
        <message>The message text here...</message>
    </post>
    <post>
        <username>Smorty</username>
        <tags>
            <tag>#noob</tag>
            <tag>#awesome</tag>
        </tags>
        <real_name>Morty Smith</real_name>
        <post_date>Apr. 1, 2017</post_date>
        <profile_url>https://example.com/profiles/Smorty</profile_url>
        <is_mod>True</is_mod>
        <followers>537</followers>
        <allow_pm>True</allow_pm>
        <message>The message text here...</message>
    </post>
    <post>
        <username>TheRealJerry</username>
        <allow_pm>True</allow_pm>
        <tags>
            <tag>#colorwheel</tag>
            <tag>#weird</tag>
            <tag>#huh</tag>
            <tag>#yumadbro</tag>
            <tag>#firstpost</tag>
            <tag>#plutoisaplanet</tag>
            </tags>
        <real_name>Jerry Smith</real_name>
        <post_date>May. 18, 2017</post_date>
        <profile_url>https://example.com/profiles/TheRealJerry</profile_url>
        <is_mod>False</is_mod>
        <followers>3</followers>
        <message>The message text here...</message>
    </post>
</posts>
```

Comment: `IDENTIFIED BY '<post>'`?

Comment: @lad2025 If use `IDENTIFIED BY '<post>'` using the xml above it only creates 3 rows and the tag field is null for each record.

Comment: So basically you want redundant data for each tag?

Comment: @lad2025 correct this is just staging, it makes it easier to then import it into 3 tables post, tag, post_tags, where posts and tags have an N-N (many to many) relationship and not insert duplicate tags;